# Add a primary key column in to a no primay key old table

Tags: mysql, primary-key

If a table, data might be duplicated amount rows,
and there is not primary key for every row,

can i add an column to be a primary key?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Yes. Add a new column and set it as the primary key with `AUTO_INCREMENT`. Doing so will create a new column and automatically add a unique id for each row.

```
ALTER TABLE old_table ADD pk_column INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY;
```

Comment: usually you want primary column to be first so:
`ALTER TABLE old_table ADD pk_column INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY FIRST;`

Answer (score 19):

This is possible with [ALTER TABLE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html) (Assuming you have a column that you want to use as a PK)

```
ALTER TABLE table 
ADD PRIMARY KEY(column)
```

Alternativly:

```
ALTER TABLE table 
ADD your_pk_column INT(11) AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
```