# How to set primary key with auto increment in MYSQL

Tags: mysql

```
CREATE TABLE `journal` (
  `yearr` int(4) NOT NULL,
  `monthh` char(3) NOT NULL,
  `volume` int(4) NOT NULL,
  `issue` int(4) NOT NULL,
  `pagefromto` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `pissn` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `eissn` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `author1` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `author2` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `doc` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
)

ALTER TABLE `journal`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`yearr`,`volume`,`issue`,`pagefromto`,`pissn`);
```

I need to add another key with auto increment to the above table structure

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add a primary key column in to a no primay key old table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4574866/add-a-primary-key-column-in-to-a-no-primay-key-old-table)

Comment: Have you tried reading [the documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/example-auto-increment.html)?

Comment: It's not clear if you want to add an auto_increment field to your table and primary key or you want to add an auto_increment field to your table and make that the primary key and amend your current primary key to a unique key.

Comment: I am unable to set up more than 5 Primary Keys in a table (mysql).  According to the search results from internet, it states that we can declare 16 Primary Keys AT MOST.  In the above table (journal), I wanted to use 6 PKs (`yearr`,`volume`,`issue`,`pagefromto`,`pissn` and journalid-AutoIncrement)

Comment: please read my answer. You do not want to add PKs on these. You want to add a unique index on these. It is very important to understand the difference. 99.99% of the time, you want your PK to be a auto increment ID. Exceptions to this are extremely rare. Even many-to-many relationship tables should have an autoincrement PK.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit confusing. You say you want to add a second primary key which will be auto increment... This doesn't make sense. They are called PRIMARY keys for a reason. There is only one primary key on a table as it is the, well, **Primary** key.

What I think you want to do is have a auto increment ID to use as the PK, which you could include in your create table like Arshad answered.

At that point, what you want to do is use your auto increment ID as the primary key (the same way you did with your PK, but put only the new ID in the PK, not the rest of your fields.), and you will want to use a unique index to make sure the combination of (`yearr`,`volume`,`issue`,`pagefromto`,`pissn`) doesn't repeat.

See [this document](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-index.html) to get more info on index creation

Note that if your table is already created, you'll have to delete the old primary key before you can add it on the ID.

Answer (score -1):

You can use this query. This will create table with "id" as AutoIncrement and primary key

```
CREATE TABLE 
      tbl_employee (  
       id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
       employee_id int(4) NOT NULL,  
       employee_no int(6) NOT NULL,
       employee_name varchar(60) NOT NULL,
       department_id int(4) NOT NULL,
       designation_id int(4) NOT NULL,
       hired_date date NOT NULL,
       salary int(10) NOT NULL,
       PRIMARY KEY(id)
    )
```

Comment: I am sorry, this table (tbl_employee) was mistakenly posted.